# Is there a way to solve this question using instantaneous center method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, kinetic-theory

This question is about instantaneous center method of finding velocities. I saw this question on a exam paper, but i think the question may be wrong because i couldn't find a way to get IC(1,3)
Or velocity of B, related to earth.

[image: question]